# Is $|z-i| = |z+i|$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I computed a Mobius transformation $-\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ that maps the upper half plane to a disk, with i mapping to the center of the disk, $w = 0$.

How do I know that the disk is a unit disk and not anything bigger or smaller?

I tried using the definition of modulus: $w = f(z) = |\frac{z-i}{z+i}| = \sqrt{\frac{x^2+(y-1)^2} { x^2+(y+1)^2}}$, but does this equal $1$?

Or, better still, is $|z-1| = |z+1|$ and $|z-2| = |z+2|$, etc.  Is there such a relation?

Thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such nice relation. You can plug in $z=i$, $z=1$, and $z=2$ into you title equation and last two equations respectively to see that none of these work out (and why no such relation will be true in general)

Comment: $z=i$ is a trivial counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: to compare $|z-a|$ and $|z+a|$, what happens when $z=a$ (or $z=-a$)? Can there be any meaningful relationship between them?

Comment: very good point, @cameronwilliams; that'd give me 0 = |2a| and vice versa , which is nonsense.  Then...how can I know that the image mapping is indeed a unit disk ...and not some arbitrarily large / small disk?

Comment: I'm guessing it would have to come from the context of the problem, @cameronwilliams.  But for now I have $e^{i\pi}$ (z-i)/(z+i), just from using symmetry:  i and -i are symmetric w.r.t. to the real axis, but they map to 0 and $\infty$, respectively, which tells us the image of the real axis must be a circle centered at the origin (symmetry preservation of linear fractional transformations).  Then i mapping to 0 tells us that the UHP maps to the interior of the disk.  Now, my only problem left is ...how big is this disk?

Comment: The reason that it works out is that - as you showed - $$\frac{|z-i|}{|z+i|} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}}.$$ The denominator is larger than the numerator in general since $(y-1)^2 \le (y+1)^2$ for $y \ge 0$ (i.e. for those $z$ in the upper half plane). Hence $$\frac{|z-i|}{|z+i|} \le 1.$$

Comment: oh, gosh... :-( of course.  Thanks so much @CameronWilliams!!

Comment: You're very welcome! Sometimes you lose sight of the forest despite all of the trees right in front of you. It happens to all of us.

Comment: yes... for z in the UHP, so for y greater than or equal to zero, the quotient is less than or equal to 1.  Thanks for adding the context that I was looking for, too, @cameronwilliams.  Tip of the tongue...I just couldn't spell it out for some reason...

Comment: exactly.... :-(

Answer (score 4):

In fact, $$\vert z+i\vert=\vert z-i\vert$$ is satisfied by no $z\in\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R.$ Square each side to get $$(z+i)(\bar z-i)=(\bar z+i)(z-i)$$ which expands to $$z\bar z+i(\bar z-z)+1=z\bar z+i(z-\bar z)+1$$ or $$\bar z=z\implies z\in\mathbb R.$$ General relations like $$\vert z+a\vert=\vert z-a\vert$$ if $a\in\mathbb C$ can be solved similarly: we get $$(z+a)(\bar z-\bar a)=(z-a)(\bar z+\bar a)$$ or $$a\bar z-\bar az=0$$ after some manipulation. What number must be real for this to hold?

Answer (score 0):

The locus of points that are equidistant from two points is the perpendicular bisector of the segment connecting the two points. The locus of points so that $|z+i|=|z-i|$ is the set of points on the perpendicular bisector of the segment connecting $-i$ and $i$; that is, the real axis. Thus, the locus of points so that $\left|\frac{z+i}{z-i}\right|=1$ is the real axis. In other words, $\frac{z+i}{z-i}$ is on the unit circle if and only if $z$ is real.